# How can I obtain an object from a listview data template?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview and I'm using gridview with 3 columns. The first column displays the name of an object called CanvasView that I have as the ItemsSource of the listview. The next two gridview columns are buttons that need the CanvasView object from that list that is the ItemsSource. How can I obtain that?

XAML for the ItemsSource:

```
<ListView x:Name="ViewsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CanvasViews, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectionChanged="ViewsList_SelectionChanged" Loaded="ViewsList_Loaded" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="ViewNameTextBox" Height="20" Width="60" Grid.Column="0"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=ViewName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly}" BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderColor}">
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Go">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="GoToView" Style="{StaticResource TinyRoundedButton}" Click="GoToView_Click"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Delete">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteView" Style="{StaticResource TinyRoundedButton}" Foreground="#BFE83131" Click="DeleteView_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here's the click event where I need the object:

```
private void GoToView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

I need to obtain the object that is on the same row as the button. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do, what do you need the row item for and *where* do you need it? A two way binding on the ItemsSource property is pointless.

Comment: I'm needing it on a click event for the button. I'm needing the object so I can pull data from it. That data specifically being a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `Button` is inherited from the `DataTemplate` (because you haven't assigned it explicitly). And the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is always the data item of the actual row/item the template is applied on.

```cs
private void GoToView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var button = sender as Button;
  var canvasViewItem = button.DataContext as CanvasView;
}
```